# How to do pixel perfect collision detection with Rabbyt?

Tags: python, collision-detection, pyglet

I have started looking into the Rabbyt library and so far I am really enjoying using it in combination with pyglet.

One thing that does not seem to be implemented in the library is pixel perfect collision detection between sprites. I have two problems in implementing that.

First of all, I am using pyglet to load the textures for the sprites, but I can't understand how to obtain bit masks from the textures (my very limited OpenGL knowledge being the main problem). It seems that the BufferImageMask is obtained from the AbstractImage instance, but not from the texture itself. What is the right way to do that?

Secondly, what are the different ways to implement the actual collision detection algorithm? I am mostly interested if there are any ways/variations, as everything that I have read so far is like this:

[Collision Detection Algorithm @ gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/collision-detection-r735)

I am just trying not to miss any crucial information out, the algorithm itself is solid.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am coding in Python 2.7 but I would rather implement the actual pixel perfect collision detection algorithm in C and use it as an extension.

### Update

I have managed to get pixel perfect collision detection working with non-rotated sprites:

```
    r1 = collision[entity1].aabb
    r2 = collision[entity2].aabb
    sprite1 = renderable[entity1].sprite
    sprite2 = renderable[entity2].sprite
    ri = r1.intersect(r2)


    offx1, offy1 = int(ri.left - r1.left), int(ri.top - r1.top)
    offx2, offy2 = int(ri.left - r2.left), int(ri.top - r2.top)

    d1 = sprite1.texture.get_image_data().get_data('A', sprite1.texture.width)
    d2 = sprite2.texture.get_image_data().get_data('A', sprite2.texture.width)

    p1 = cast(d1, POINTER(c_ubyte))
    p2 = cast(d2, POINTER(c_ubyte))

    for i in range(0, int(ri.width)):
        for j in range(0, int(ri.height)):
            c1, c2 = 0, 0
            x1 = offx1+i
            y1 = (j+offy1)*sprite1.texture.width
            x2 = offx2+i
            y2 = (offy2+j)*sprite2.texture.width

            if x1 >= 0 and y1 >= 0:
                c1 = p1[x1 + y1]

            if x2 >= 0 and y2 >= 0:
                c2 = p2[x2 + y2]

            if c1>0 and c2 >0:
                pairs.add(pair)
                break
```

collision and renderable are simply dicts of objects that are associated with the given entity. The algorithm is a modified version of this one : [Pyglet pixel perfect collision](http://code.google.com/p/darkcoda/source/browse/sprite_collision/collide.py)

While that is pretty good (and fast, even for hacked together code like that) it is useless for rotated sprites(which I need, unless caching about 100 different versions of the same sprite for different angles is a viable option), so I am still looking for a solution to that problem.

Comment: You should post this on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Was my answer to the update useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the update**

The following pseudo-code might do the trick:

```
...

middleX1 = sprite1.texture.width/2
middleY1 = sprite1.texture.height/2

middleX2 = sprite2.texture.width/2
middleY2 = sprite2.texture.height/2

angle1 = ?   #Radians.
vX11 = -cos(angle1)
vY11 = -sin(angle1)
vX12 = -cos(angle1 + math.pi/2)
vY12 = -sin(angle1 + math.pi/2)

angle2 = ?   #Radians.
vX21 = -cos(angle2)
vY21 = -sin(angle2)
vX22 = -cos(angle2 + math.pi/2)
vY22 = -sin(angle2 + math.pi/2)

for ...
    for ...

        ...

        aX1 = x1 - middleX1
        aY1 = j+offy1 - middleY1
        aX2 = x2 - middleX2
        aY2 = j+offy2 - middleY2

        tX1 = vX11*aX1 + vY11*aY1 + middleX1
        tY1 = vX12*aX1 + vY12*aX1 + middleY1

        tX2 = vX21*aX2 + vY21*aY2 + middleX2
        tY2 = vX22*aX2 + vY22*aX2 + middleY2

        #Use tX* and tY* for indexing. Remember to multiply tY* with width.

        ...
```

This SHOULD work, assuming angles are clock-wise and in radians, and that rotations should happen around the middle of each sprite. Basically, it is a bit of vector and matrix math hand-coded. A neater and more maintainable solution would use matrices, but I don't know a lot of Python, so I decided to avoid that.

The math works by, for each point in each image, finding its relative position to the middle, rotating it by multiplying the coordinates with unit-vectors along the new axes of the rotation, and finally adding the middle back to get the non-relative coordinate.

Comment: I implemented this using matrices and it works. It is very slow and has convinced me to use convex hulls (which did not turn out to be that hard to implement, using the separating axis theory) wherever possible, instead of pixel perfect collision.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot answer the first question regarding pyglet, textures and images (I found a method called "get_image_data" in Texture in the online API; maybe that can be used?),
I can answer the second question.

Apart from the method you provided in the link, I know at least two other methods: The first is using OpenGL, draw the images to a buffer, and check whether they overlap. I have no idea how fast this is, but I could imagine it is slow. It does support rotation and scaling, however.

The second is somewhat similar to the one you have given; but instead of finding the intersection of two axis-aligned bounding boxes and only check inside the intersection, the intersection of two convex hulls are found and checked. One advantage of this is that convex hulls generally provides a better fit, and another is that the convex hulls can be rotated, while axis-aligned bounding boxes cannot. The main disadvantage is that convex hull intersection is much more complex than axis-aligned bounding box intersection, so it can be difficult to implement.

I have written a library that utilizes the second method; you can find it at [PoxelColl](https://github.com/Poxelcoll/Poxelcoll). It should be faster than other pixel-perfect collision detection libraries, especially for rotation and scaling. I don't know if you can use it from Python; There is a Scala-version if you use Jython, and a C++ version that you might be able to make a binding to in Python, but that might be a fair amount of extra work. So if you don't need scaling or rotation, it might be a better idea to simply implement the version you have already found and test if it is fast enough.

Comment: I definitely need rotation as most entities in the game are non animated long hulls(ships). Interestingly enough, Rabbyt's AABB collision detection has worked fine with rotated sprites which bewilders me to great extent.
I will look into convex hulls but that might be too complex for me at the moment.

Comment: While AA bounding boxes cannot be rotated, there are ways around it. You can either rotate the sprite, and go through all the pixels to find the new bounding box, which is precise but slow, or you can rotate the points of the bounding box and find the AA bounding box of that, which is fast but imprecise. I don't know which method Rabbyt is using.

The PoxelColl library should handle the convex hulls for you. It is complex to implement, so if you want to implement it yourself, rotating each image, finding the AABB of it, and using that for collision detection is simple and may be fast enough.

Comment: Rabbyt just renders the sprite transformed, but the source texture is untouched. I don't rotate the bounding boxes at all (sorry for the confusion), I just have a big enough square box to accomodate all rotations without clipping. I know that's the caveman way of doing it but so far it is the one thing I can wrap my head around.

Comment: If you want to focus on making a game, just use the method you can wrap your head around and make it work. If it turns out to be fast enough, you are home free, and if it turns out to be too slow, you can always spend more time on it or get help. Alternatively, you can do what many great and not-so-great game designers have done in the past and cut corners, such that you don't have to support rotation. In fact, constraints can often make a game better. For instance, the dense fog in Silent Hill 1 was originally used for speed purposes, but ending up making the game better.